# Longest distance between 2 points on a cylinder

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

Given a right circular cylinder with radius $R$ and height $H=kR$, where $k$ is a positive real number, what is the longest minimal distance between $2$ points when you can only travel along the surface of the cylinder?

I see $4$ cases to consider:

1. Both points on the same base of the cylinder
2. One point on a base and one on the side
3. One point on one base and one on the other
4. Both points on the side

After quite a bit of tinkering it seems to me that the worst case scenario is having one point on the perimeter of a base and the other point on the perimeter of the other base, diametrically opposite the first point. This gives the following answer:

a. $\; k \le \frac{\pi^2}{4}-1$

$Max = (2 + k)R$

b. $\; k \gt \frac{\pi^2}{4}-1$

$Max= \sqrt {\pi^2 + k^2}R$

Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: Don't you mean the **shortest** distance, because the longest distance is infinite ?

Comment: The shortest distance is obtained by unfolding the cylinder.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the longest of the shortest distances.

Comment: @JeanMarie Could you expand on what you mean by "unfolding the cylinder"?

Comment: 1) I don't understand what you call the longest of the shortest distances 2) The xylindre is a rules surface. As such the geodesics (the curves of shortest distance) are obtained in the way I have said (cutting  the cylinder and transforming it into a rectangle, then obtaining the shortest distance curve by the line segment [AB].

Comment: @JeanMarie I meant the longest minimal distance path between any two points.

Comment: Sorry, I just understood now: you want the "diameter of the cylinder",  not in terms of Eucldean distance but in terms of geodetic distance...

Comment: It is pretty clear that the longest geodetic path on such a cylinder is the geodetic path between two antipodal points on opposite bases. But what grants you that such a path is not made by just a chord in a base, then a geodetic arc on the lateral surface?

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio Sorry, I don't understand your point. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Jens: you are assuming that there are just two kinds of longest geodetic paths (between antipodal points on opposite bases): paths entirely contained in the lateral surface, paths that travel from a point on a base to the opposite one, then reach the final point by travelling along the lateral surface. That assumption is wrong.

Comment: In some cases, the geodetic path between two antipodal points on opposite bases is made by a chord (but not a diameter) of a base, then a piece contained in the lateral surface.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio You are too fast for me. Summing up: If you think my conclusion is wrong, please post a proof. If you think it is right, please post a proof.

Comment: @Jens: I think I spent enough time on this problem. You may prove just the same: fix a value for $k$ and compute the shape of the longest geodetic path.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio No problem. Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your results:
1) With a simple logical argument on the height of the cylinder, you can establish that the 2 points have to be on the opposite bases (otherwise they would be part of smaller cylinder)
2) Assume that they are also diametrically opposite (this can be proved after the calculation of the minimal distance of such points - see 9 below)
3) The shortest path has to be a combination of a "straight line on the side" and a straight line on the face
4) You can then compute the corresponding length as (using Pythagoras for the length on the side of the unfolded cylinder, and the length of a chord for the length on the base):
$L_k(x)=2R (\sqrt{X^2+\frac{k^2}{4}}+cos(X))$ for $X \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$
5) The function has a local minimum in $X=0$, and is increasing  then decreasing over the interval (using derivation)
6) Therefore, the overall minimum is either for $X=0$ or $X=\frac{\pi}{2}$
7) You can find the value of k for which $L_k(0)=L_k(\frac{\pi}{2})$ : this gives $k=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-1$
8) This gives the values you found:
For $k \le \frac{\pi^2}{4}-1$ then $L_k(0)=R(k+2)$
For $k \ge \frac{\pi^2}{4}-1$ then $L_k(\frac{\pi}{2})=R \sqrt{\pi^2+k^2}$
NOTE: I think it is more correct to write less or equal in the first case (this means that for $k = \frac{\pi^2}{4}-1$ there are 2 different minimal paths)
9) You can then finally prove that the 2 points have to be diametrically opposite, by supposing the contrary and getting a contradiction.